# How to convert Future<String> to String

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I'm writing an app that needs to load results from a file when it starts, so time consumption is not really an issue here.

Because I don't want the whole code to be asynchronous (because I want everything to be still pretty easy to understand), I'm looking for a way to convert a `Future<String >` into a normal `String`.

I would like help at any level: If anyone knows a way to load file contents without asynchronous code, that would also be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with `await` keyword:

```
String str = await futureString;
```

or with `then` method:

```
String str;

futureString.then((result){
  str = result;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I got it working. The problem was that I tried to return that string, but I found a better solution